# My game in godot is not exporting after I add real App ID

Tags: android, export, godot, android-app-bundle

My game in godot is not exporting after I add real App ID in android manifest. I am using plugin from poing studios. It works fine with test ads and test app ID though.[image]

Godot version 3.5